# Sharepoint column not appearing in generated email

Tags: email, sharepoint-2013

I am modifying an existing SharePoint 2013 site that has an existing web form with various textboxes that the user can fill in. When this data is saved it generates an email with the info the user has entered. I added in another column and textbox for the user to fill in. Although it displays within SharePoint(After it saves), the new column & data does not display in the generated email. Any ideas what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the notification email is generated by workflow on the list, you would need to modify the workflow mail activity to include the new field.

Use SharePoint designer to check workflows for that specific list.